# How to improve unity management on android? unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

please tell me how to make the player control was not tied to the finger, but for example to drive in any part of the screen and the player will move from the point where he stopped? details in comments

```
    using UnityEngine;

    public class playerMove : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public Transform player;
    
       void OnMouseDrag()
        {
            Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

            mousePos.x = mousePos.x < -2.1f ? -2.1f : mousePos.x;
            mousePos.x = mousePos.x > 2.1f ? 2.1f : mousePos.x;
            mousePos.y = mousePos.y > 4.5f ? 4.5f : mousePos.y;
            mousePos.y = mousePos.y < -4.5f ? -4.5f : mousePos.y;

            player.position = new Vector2(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SO!   Please don't use the `unityscript` tag as Unity deprecated their JavaScript-like language many many moons ago.  It's just C# or c/c++ now, the latter via native plug-ins  :)

Comment: it is necessary that when you click on any part of the screen, the player moves from the place where he stopped,
and not where they clicked (in other words, so that the player is not stuck to the cursor)